# How to change the URL of Web API service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

An Azure App Service Web API using .NET Core was successfully deployed using the Visual Studio 2017 Publish function but now the URL needs to change.  How can I do that?

Comment: Using search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656603/rename-an-azure-function

Answer (score 0):

You could map custom DNS name to Azure App Service

1. Go to the App Service blade.
2. On the blade, find the Custom domains or bind the SSL settings.

Then you could follow the Tutorial: [Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) and the Tutorial: [Bind an existing custom SSL certificate to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl).
As both API Apps and Web Apps share the same underlying infrastructure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Anon_unique, any more problems? If this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!